# Bug? Can get point into the middle of a run of characters with a replacing display spec

Tags: text-editing, minor-mode, text-properties

I'm implementing a minor mode that "folds" certain strings.  It does this by adding a font-lock keywords rule to the buffer, that applies display properties that make it look like it's a single character.  (For example, the six-character sequence `\u00B6` might be displayed as `¶` when the mode is active.)

The documentation says that Emacs will not let point get into the middle of a run of text that's hidden this way, and that's *mostly* true, but I found a way to do it.  Start with point right *before* the visible `¶`. Type <kbd>C-d</kbd>, which deletes the `\`; the font-lock rule no longer applies and the `u00B6` reappears; point is now right before the `u`.  Then type a new <kbd>\</kbd> .  The font-lock rule applies again, the `\u00B6` disappears and `¶` reappears.  Point appears to be after the `¶`, but it is actually in between the `\` and the `u`.  Motion commands will remove point from the inside of the run, but if the very next thing you type is a self-inserting character, it will be inserted in between the `\` and the `u`.  Depending on the details of the font-lock rule, it will either not appear at all, or it will make the rule cease to match.

What can I do from within my minor mode to prevent this from happening?  It seems like it might be a bug in Emacs, but I'd rather not wait for it to be fixed.

(All testing with Emacs 27.1. Adding the cursor-intangible property to the run of text, in the same way, does not help. Cut down version of the mode follows.)

```
(define-minor-mode fold-demo-mode
  "Folding bug demo"
  :init-value nil
  :lighter " FD"
  :keymap nil
  (make-variable-buffer-local 'font-lock-extra-managed-props)
  (let ((case-fold-search nil)
        (demo-fl-rule '(("\\\\u00[bB]6" 0
                         '(face font-lock-string-face
                           display "¶"))))
        (refontify
         (lambda ()
           (save-excursion
             (goto-char (point-min))
             (while (re-search-forward "\\\\u00[bB]6" nil t)
               (save-excursion
                 (font-lock-fontify-region
                  (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0))))))))

  (if fold-demo-mode
      (progn
        ;; When the mode is being turned on, refontify after
        ;; adding to font-lock-extra-managed-props and
        ;; adding the extra fontification rule.
        (push 'display font-lock-extra-managed-props)
        (font-lock-add-keywords nil demo-fl-rule)
        (funcall refontify))

    ;; But when the mode is being turned off, remove the extra
    ;; fontification rule, refontify, and only then remove 'display
    ;; from font-lock-extra-managed-props; otherwise the display
    ;; spec won't get cleared.
    (font-lock-remove-keywords nil demo-fl-rule)
    (funcall refontify)
    (setq font-lock-extra-managed-props
          (cl-remove 'display font-lock-extra-managed-props
                     :count 1)))))
```

Comment: If you think it's a bug then `M-x report-emacs-bug` for starters.

Comment: @phils https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=45054 , but the question I asked was "What can I do from within my minor mode to prevent this from happening", _whether or not_ it counts as a bug.

Comment: You might want to link in the question to the bug you (apparently) reported: https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=45054